# Spring mvc not recognizing date with pattern MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc

I have a javascript date object with time set to end of day next year.

```
dateTemp = new Date();
endDate=new Date(dateTemp.getFullYear()+1, dateTemp.getMonth(), dateTemp.getDate(), 23, 59, 59, 999);
```

On the backend in my DTO object i have a Date object

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private Date endDate;
```

This does not populate and comes as null. If i remove HH:mm:ss then it works. But i would like to capture hours, minutes and seconds also. How is that possible?

I am using a form with a bootstrap datepicker field

Comment: It's not clear from your question what is going on. How is the date being passed from your client to your backend? Have you debugged to see what the serialized data is for your date field? Specifically, are the hours, minutes, and seconds being passed from your client to the backend?

Comment: It appears that you're also passing milliseconds there - but your format stops after seconds.

Comment: Understanding how the JavaScript object is turned into a String, and what is the exact value of that string before it's sent back to the server is key here. We can't really help unless that information is discovered.

Comment: I have a bootstrap datepicker field in a form. There is a format option on the datepicker but i believe it does not allow HH:mm:ss

Comment: Open your browser's network console and look at what is sent in the request.

Comment: I see date passed as 03/17/2015 under Form Data.

Comment: Then that is the format you need to use (or maybe javascript let's you change it).

Comment: Do you want the user to actually pick the time of day or just pick the date? Does timezone vary / matter?

Comment: I actually wanted to set the time automatically to end of day w/o prompting the user. But seems like the bootstrap datepicker plugin i use does not allow that capability. I have worked around the issue by setting the time on the backend.